# Mutate All columns in a list of tibbles

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Lets suppose I have the following list of tibbles:

```r
a_list_of_tibbles <- list(
  a = tibble(a = rnorm(10)),
  b = tibble(a = runif(10)), 
  c = tibble(a = letters[1:10])
)
```

Now I want to map them all into a single dataframe/tibble, which is not possible due to the differing column types.

How would I go about this?

I have tried this, but I want to get rid of the for loop

```r
for(i in 1:length(a_list_of_tibbles)){
  a_list_of_tibbles[[i]] <- a_list_of_tibbles[[i]] %>% mutate_all(as.character)
}
```

Then I run:

```r
map_dfr(.x = a_list_of_tibbles, .f = as_tibble)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do the computation within the `map` - use `across` instead of the suffix `_all` (which is getting deprecated) to loop over the columns of the dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(a_list_of_tibbles, 
     ~.x %>%
       mutate(across(everything(), as.character) %>%
       as_tibble))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 30 × 1
   a                 
   <chr>             
 1 0.735200825884485 
 2 1.4741501589461   
 3 1.39870958697574  
 4 -0.36046362308853 
 5 -0.893860999301402
 6 -0.565468636033674
 7 -0.075270267983768
 8 2.33534260196058  
 9 0.69667906338348  
10 1.54213170143702  
# … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: I just don't understand the point of this question. At first I thought they want `bind_cols`. Anyway, your answer gives OP what they want, but you cannot tell me why they want that :) +1

Comment: I want it because I have a script I run that reads in excel files that are supposed to be uniform (all columns are the same type in all files....yeah fat chance) so my map_dfr was blowing up due to column type mismatch

Comment: @M--  Probably, their example may not be accurate.  It may be that they have some datasets in the list with different column types.  Thus, they are converting to a single type and binding as `bind_rows` will throw error with different data types.  i.e. even if the column shows 1 observation with character value, it becomes character class and thus the binding is difficult

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator don't get me wrong, I wasn't criticizing you or your question, just couldn't think of a scenario that this would be needed. Cheers

Comment: @M-- yeah no problem, it happens quite often enough for me anyways that I thought posing the question would help others out there, when you unleash a spreadsheet to be filled out with the requisite instructions...expect chaos and nothing done the way you asked lol

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map_depth(a_list_of_tibbles, 2, as.character) %>%
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 30 × 1
#>    a                 
#>    <chr>             
#>  1 0.0894618169853206
#>  2 -1.50144637645091 
#>  3 1.44795821718513  
#>  4 0.0795342912030257
#>  5 -0.837985570593029
#>  6 -0.050845557103668
#>  7 0.031194556366589 
#>  8 0.0989551909839589
#>  9 1.87007290229274  
#> 10 0.67816212007413  
#> # … with 20 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: very cool, thanks for posting